# How to animate an image by pressing a button in Swift 5. (OOP)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

your helped me the last time a lot and now I need your help again.
My Problem is to animate an image while tapping on a button. To detect, when the button is tapped I have done a struct with a boolean. But when I tap on the button, the image don't change/animate. Can somebody help me?
Thanks :)

My GameScene:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

struct Animation {
    static var pressed = false
}

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var auswahl : CarMenu!
    
    var spieler: Hero!

    var rechts = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rechts")
    var links = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "links")
    var jumpPic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jump")
    var shootPic = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shoot")
    var isTouchedRight: Bool = false
    var isTouchedLeft: Bool = false
    var isJumping: Bool = false
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
//        soldat3()
        gehLinks()
        gehRechts()
        jumpButton()
        shootButton()
        self.spieler = Hero()
        self.auswahl = CarMenu()
        print("\(Variables.counter)")
        spieler.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
      
        
        
    addChild(spieler)
      
    }
    
    func gehRechts() {
    rechts.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)
        rechts.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 1.3, y: self.size.height / 2.4)
     rechts.alpha = 0.20
        
        self.addChild(rechts)
    }
     
    func gehLinks() {
    links.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)
        links.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 7, y: self.size.height / 2.4)
     links.alpha = 0.20
        self.addChild(links)
    }
    func jumpButton() {
        jumpPic.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)
        jumpPic.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 7, y: self.size.height / 2.1)
        jumpPic.alpha = 0.20
        self.addChild(jumpPic)
    }
    func shootButton() {
        shootPic.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 50)
        shootPic.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 1.12, y: self.size.height / 2.4)
        shootPic.alpha = 0.20
        self.addChild(shootPic)
       
    }
//    func soldat3() {
//        if auswahl.counter == "Auto1" {
//            print("\(auswahl)")
//        } else {
//        print("nichts gefunden")
//        }
//    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchlocation = touch!.location(in: self)
        if rechts.contains(touchlocation) {
            isTouchedRight = true
            isTouchedLeft = false
            Animation.pressed = true
           
        } else if links.contains(touchlocation) {
            isTouchedLeft = true
          isTouchedRight = false
            Animation.pressed = true
            
        } else if spieler.action(forKey: "jump") == nil && jumpPic.contains(touchlocation) {
            isTouchedLeft = false
            isTouchedRight = false
     isJumping = true
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchlocation = touch!.location(in: self)
        if rechts.contains(touchlocation) {
            isTouchedRight = false
            isTouchedLeft = false
            isJumping = false
            Animation.pressed = false
        } else if links.contains(touchlocation) {
            isTouchedLeft = false
          isTouchedRight = false
            isJumping = false
            Animation.pressed = false
        } else if jumpPic.contains(touchlocation) {
            isTouchedLeft = false
          isTouchedRight = false
            isJumping = false
        }
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
       
        if isTouchedRight == true {
            spieler.position = CGPoint(x: spieler.position.x + 2, y: spieler.position.y)
        } else if isTouchedLeft == true {
            spieler.position = CGPoint(x: spieler.position.x - 2, y: spieler.position.y)
        } else if isJumping == true {
            let jumpUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 50, duration: 0.4)
            let fallBack = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -50, duration: 0.4)
            
            spieler.run(SKAction.sequence([jumpUp, fallBack]),withKey: "jump" )
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

================================================================================================

```
My HeroClass 


import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Hero: SKSpriteNode {

    var Spieler: CarMenu!
    
    var player : SKSpriteNode
    
    init() {
        self.player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 44))
   //     print("\(Spieler.counter)")
        player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")
        player.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 200)
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
        player.setScale(0.4)
      
    animationPlayer()
      Soldat2()
        addChild(player)
    }
    
    
    
    

    func shoot() {
        let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
        bullet.position.x = player.position.x + 20
        bullet.position.y = player.position.y + 30
        self.addChild(bullet)
        
        let move = SKAction.moveBy(x: self.size.height + bullet.frame.size.height, y: 0, duration: 2.0)
        let delete = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        bullet.run(SKAction.sequence([move, delete]))
    }
    func moveRight() {
        let moveRechts = SKAction.moveTo(x: player.position.x + 20, duration: 2.0)
        player.run(moveRechts)
    }
    func moveLeft() {
        let moveLinks = SKAction.moveTo(x: player.position.x - 20, duration: 2.0)
        player.run(moveLinks)
    }
  func Soldat2() {
       if Variables.counter == "Auto2" {
        print("Klappt")
        self.player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Soldat2")
        player.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 120)
        
       } else if Variables.counter == "Auto1"{
         print("normal")
        self.player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")
        player.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 120)
       }
   }
```

// Here is the important point:

```
    func animationPlayer() {
    
        
        while Animation.pressed == true {
            print("Tapped")
            player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "1")

        var playerArray : [SKTexture] = []


            for index in 1...6 {
                print("Klappt")
            playerArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(index)"))
                print("klappt2")
                addChild(player)
        }

            player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: playerArray, timePerFrame: 0.8)))

        }
        
    }
    
  
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: I think the code will not execute in your loop because you are adding "addChild(player)" multiple times?

Comment: Well, without the addChild(player) in the loop its still doesnt work

Comment: Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568667/skaction-not-running-when-button-is-held/66573376#66573376) could help you?